# How do I add multiple negative joins in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I would like to exclude employees from employee collection with the hire date after 01/01/2020 and the status as active from the bonus collection. So I need to do a negative join with the employee collection and have 2 criteria. Here is my sample

```
join

q: bonus>0
fq: -{!join from = employeeid to = employeeid fromIndex = employee}(hiredate:["01/01/2020" to *] AND status:active)
```

I have tried the above query however it returns the following error

> "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse
>   '(hiredate:["01/01/2020" to *]': Encountered \"\" at line 1,
>   column 15.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n     ...\n
>
>    ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n     ...\n    \"(\"
>   ...\n    \")\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    \"^\" ...\n     ...\n
>    ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    
>   ...\n    \"filter(\" ...\n     ...\n    ",

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: You could index `bonus` into employee index as well so that you would just have to apply a simple fq on it.

Comment: The `hiredate` format you're using won't do what you're expecting it to as well. It seems you've indexed it as a string (a date would have to be formatted like `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`). When using `TO` (it should be capitialized) it'd give you any tokens that sort after `01/01/2020` - meaning anything that starts with `02` etc., regardless of year.

Comment: To simplify the question, solr throws an error when trying to perform a negative join on multiple fields so for e.g -{!join from = employeeid to = employeeid fromIndex = employee}status:active works fine however -{!join from = employeeid to = employeeid fromIndex = employee}(Name:"XYZ" AND status:active) throws error. Same thing works properly for positive join when we remove - from the join. Please suggest